# Ruby on Rails - No route matches [GET] "/signup" when refreshing browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am getting a wierd error. I am using `button_to` with the `method` set to `post` to move between a landing page and a sign up page. This part is working, I can navigate using the buttons but if I refresh my browser (`F5`, `Ctrl + F5`, `Ctrl + R`) I get

> No route matches [GET] "/signup"

My route is: `post 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'`

My button is: `<%= button_to "Sign Up", signup_path, method: :post, :class => 'appBTNs' %>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says you don't have a GET request defined because you don't. you have a POST request. When you submit a form you should redirect to a get route. if you don't redirect then when you submit you're on a route that doesn't have a view and you can't make a GET request to it.

If you're trying to submit the form with that button, it should be to 'users#create' and the create action in the controller can 
`redirect_to root_path` so that after you submit you're on a different page.

Answer (score -1):

signup is `POST request` and not `GET request`,
Instead of `post 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'` it should be
`post 'signup', to: 'users#create', as: 'signup'`

to signup you must pass `params` to `'users#create'` method and not to `'users#new'` method.
`'users#new'` method mostly returns blank user object.